# wifi is not working after updating 18.10

Tags: wireless, 18.10

NO WIFI ADAPTER FOUND

```
naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$ lspci -knn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:1904] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Dell Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:9d2f] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [8086:9d31] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:9d60] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:9d61] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 [8086:9d3a] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:9d03] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:9d15] (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d48] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller [1028:078a]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC [8086:9d21] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP PMC [1028:078a]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [8086:9d23] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP SMBus [1028:078a]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [1028:078a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169


naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for naushad: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 54:48:10:b4:15:c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d1004000-d1004fff memory:d1000000-d1003fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20f0u2
       serial: 9e:2e:54:a0:db:9a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.49 link=yes multicast=yes
naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$
```

Edit #1:

~$ dkms status

```
btusb, 4.0, 4.18.0-16-generic, x86_64: installed 
oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1734600-4.4, 4.1: added 
radeon-si, 1a, 4.4.0-38-generic, x86_64: built
```

~$ ls -al /usr/src

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Mar 11 23:05 btusb-4.0  
drw-r-xr-x  2 root root 4096 May 29  2018 btusb-qca-rome-1.3  
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Mar  4 00:07 linux-headers-4.18.0-15  
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Mar  4 00:07 linux-headers-4.18.0-15-generic
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Mar  6 19:09 linux-headers-4.18.0-1  
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Mar  6 19:09 linux-headers-4.18.0-16-generic  
drw-r-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Dec  9 00:24 oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1734600-4.4-4.1  
drw-r-xr-x  3 root root 4096 May 29  2018 radeon-si-1a
```

PLEASE HELP ME.

Comment: please tell me command

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `dkms status`. Is your wireless adapter internal, or via external USB adapter? Did this work before? Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 0):

With the `dkms status` command, we can see that only one bluetooth dkms driver is installed, but the wi-fi and radeon drivers are not installed. That's probably why the wi-fi isn't working.

```
btusb, 4.0, 4.18.0-16-generic, x86_64: installed 
oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1734600-4.4, 4.1: added 
radeon-si, 1a, 4.4.0-38-generic, x86_64: built
```

I assume that you're running with the `4.18.0-16-generic` kernel, yes?

Where did you get the wi-fi and radeon drivers from?

Did wi-fi work BEFORE the 18.10 update?

**Update #1:**

In `terminal`...

`sudo dkms build oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1734600-4.4/4.1`

if it builds OK, then...

`sudo dkms install oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1734600-4.4/4.1`

if it installs OK, then...

`dkms status`

Try wi-fi.

**Update #2:**

This dkms module hasn't been used for quite a while, so we remove it...

`sudo dkms remove radeon-si/1a -k 4.4.0-38-generic`

**Update #3:**

This dkms.conf module is hard-coded for an earlier kernel, so it won't build on this current kernel. So we remove it also...

`sudo dkms remove oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1734600-4.4/4.1 -k $(uname -r)`

Comment: yes wifi work well before update. i have searched from google for wifi adapter

Comment: @NafisAlam you need to answer the rest of my questions so I can update my answer.

Comment: yes wifi work well before update. i have searched from google for wifi adapter . i used some command but i am new so little understand of ubuntu. I have also mention the output of  ls -al /usr/src

Comment: @NafisAlam please do my Update #1 in my answer. Edit your question with the output of all commands... and use copy/paste please.

Comment: @heynnema First the adapter should appear in lsusb. Tinkering with drivers won't help.

Comment: @Pilot6 please DO jump in and ask for your lsusb command string. I'll take the help. There's very little info to go on, and I saw the dkms problem, so I figured that I'd start there... but you may be absolutely correct.

Comment: I mean `lspci`. It is not there.

Comment: @Pilot6 I didn't see it there either, but they say it worked before the 18.10 upgrade... then I saw the oem dkms driver...

Comment: Drivers can't spoil it to disappear completely. Maybe it is an SDIO Broadcom one?

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't know what a SDIO Broadcom is. This is very much your field of expertise than mine :-)

Comment: I am not an expert either. Jeremy31 is.

Comment: naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$ sudo dkms build oem-wifi-qualcomm-ath10k-lp1734600-4.4/4.1
[sudo] password for naushad: 
8Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for naushad: 
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$

Comment: naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:28c0 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 22d9:276a  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$

Comment: @NafisAlam Please take the fresh terminal output for the last two comments, and copy/paste them as an edit to your question. Do not copy/paste from the comments. Your wi-fi module won't build on this current kernel, and I don't know if that's what we needed anyway... as your lspci command doesn't even show your wi-fi hardware... so it's impossible to know how to get it working for you. You can do Update #2 and #3 from my answer.